# Play audio upon each button click

Tags: java, android, audio, android-studio

My project has 2 audio files, 'dog.mp3' and 'cat.mp3' and so the code below enables me to play either sound based on particular list view item clicks however how can I modify the code so that I want to achieve the following?:

- When 'cat.mp3' is playing, if I tap the list view item for 'dog.mp3', I want the 'cat.mp3' file to stop playing and the 'dog.mp3' audio to play.
- When 'dog.mp3' is playing, if I tap the list view item for 'cat.mp3', I want the 'dog.mp3' file to stop playing and the 'cat.mp3' audio to play.

All help will be appreciated.

```
mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(Test.this, R.raw.cat);   
            mp.start();
            }

            if (position == 1) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(Test.this, R.raw.dog);   
            mp.start();
            }
        }
    });
```

**ERROR**

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView mainList;

    String[] listContent = {
            "chimes", "chord", "ding",
            "notify", "recycle", "ringin",
            "ringout", "tada"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.main_listView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listContent);
        mainList.setAdapter(adapter);

        int[] resID = { R.raw.chimes, R.raw.chord, R.raw.ding,
                R.raw.notify, R.raw.recycle, R.raw.ringin, R.raw.ringout, R.raw.tada };

        mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                playSong(position);

            }
        });


        public void playSong(int songIndex) {
            // Play song
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(resID[songIndex]);

            mp.start();
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // variable declaration
    private ListView mainList;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private final String[] listContent = { "chimes", "chord", "ding", "notify",
            "recycle", "ringin", "ringout", "tada" };

    private final int[] resID = { R.raw.chimes, R.raw.chord, R.raw.ding,
            R.raw.notify, R.raw.recycle, R.raw.ringin, R.raw.ringout,
            R.raw.tada };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Initializing variables
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mainList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_listView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContent);
        mainList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                playSong(position);

            }
        });

    }

    public void playSong(int songIndex) {
        // Play song
        mp.reset();// stops any current playing song
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), resID[songIndex]);// create's
                                                                            // new
                                                                            // mediaplayer
                                                                            // with
                                                                            // song.
        // if you don't know what is getApplicationContext() here better use
        // MainActivity.this or yourclassname.this
        mp.start(); // starting mediaplayer
        // setting up what to do if current song completes.
        /*
         * mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
         * 
         * @Override public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) { // TODO
         * Auto-generated method stub
         * 
         * } });
         */
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting errors after using your code. Please check the screenshot and my updated code above.

Comment: Add this private MediaPlayer mp; on top of onCreate() and this mp = new MediaPlayer(); after setContentView()

Comment: OK. Just 1 more error remains `Cannot resolve symbol 'resID'`.

Comment: Now check my edited answer completed as you need. That's was my mistake i gave u int parameter to datasource, really sorry about. Hope it will help you up now, if so make it as right answer.

Comment: The app runs however after playing a sound for the first time, the app crashes when I select a second sound.

Comment: can you show me your logcat details? or please provide any details of the error.

Comment: Just added logcat in your reply

Comment: Just emailed you the screenshot

Comment: check now.. hope it should run perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a `SoundPool` for this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

You can load up all the audio in your onCreate and set the maxStreams to 1 so that only one sound will play at once.